# Using ajax and $.POST not sending data to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Orginally I tried storing everything I wanted to send as variables, then inputting them in to the $.post . But it saying variables were undefined, so I made it a lot simpler by just doing this

```
$.post("uploadData.php", {
  match : document.getElementById("matchNumInput").value,
  team : document.getElementById("teamNumberInput").value,
  highMade : parseInt(document.getElementById("himd").textContent),
  highAttempt : parseInt(document.getElementById("hiat").textContent),
  lowMade : parseInt(document.getElementById("lomd").textContent),
  lowAttempt : parseInt(document.getElementById("loat").textContent),
  fouls : parseInt(document.getElementById("foulCounter").textContent),
  blocks : parseInt(document.getElementById("blockCounter").textContent), 
  picks : parseInt(document.getElementById("pickCounter").textContent),
  hang : parseFloat(document.getElementById("timer").textContent),
  comment : document.getElementById("commentsInput").value,
  obstacle1 : document.getElementById("obstacleOneCounter").textContent,
  obstacle2 : document.getElementById("obstacleTwoCounter").textContent,
  obstacle3 : document.getElementById("obstacleThreeCounter").textContent, 
  obstacle4 : document.getElementById("obstacleFourCounter").textContent,
  obstacle5 : document.getElementById("obstacleFiveCounter").textContent,
  obstacle6 : document.getElementById("obstacleSixCounter").textContent,
  obstacle7 : document.getElementById("obstacleSevenCounter").textContent,
  obstacle8 : document.getElementById("obstacleEightCounter").textContent,
  obstacle9 : document.getElementById("obstacleNineCounter").textContent,
  autoHighMade : parseInt(document.getElementById("ahimd").textContent),
  autoHighAttempt : parseInt(document.getElementById("ahiat").textContent),
  autoLowMade : parseInt(document.getElementById("alomd").textContent),
  autoLowAttempt : parseInt(document.getElementById("aloat").textContent),
  autoObstacle1 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleOneCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle2 : document.getElementById("obstacleTwoCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle3 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleThreeCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle4 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleFourCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle5 : document.getElementById("autoObstaclefiveCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle6 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleSixCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle7 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleSevenCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle8 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleEightCounter").textContent,
  autoObstacle9 : document.getElementById("autoObstacleNineCounter").textContent
});
```

Yeah, it is a lot. But it isn't getting sent to the php file. Is my syntax wrong?Should I not be sending so much in one post?

EDIT: the php is here:

```
    <?php 
$match = $_POST["match"];
$team = $_POST["team"];
$highMade = $_POST["highMade"];
$highAttempt = $_POST["highAttempt"];
$lowMade = $_POST["lowMade"]; 
$lowAttempt = $_POST["lowAttempt"];
$fouls = $_POST["fouls"];
$blocks = $_POST["blocks"]; 
$picks = $_POST["picks"];
$hang = $_POST["hang"]; 
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$obstacle1 = $_POST["obstacle1"];
$obstacle2 = $_POST["obstacle2"]; 
$obstacle3 = $_POST["obstacle3"];
$obstacle4 = $_POST["obstacle4"]; 
$obstacle5 = $_POST["obstacle5"]; 
$obstacle6 = $_POST["obstacle6"]; 
$obstacle7 = $_POST["obstacle7"]; 
$obstacle8 = $_POST["obstacle8"]; 
$obstacle9 = $_POST["obstacle9"]; 
$autoHighMade = $_POST["autoHighMade"]; 
$autoHighAttempt = $_POST["autoHighAttempt"];
$autoLowMade = $_POST["autoLowMade"]; 
$autoLowAttempt = $_POST["autoLowAttempt"];
$autoObstacle1 = $_POST["autoObstacle1"]; 
$autoObstacle2 = $_POST["autoObstacle2"]; 
$autoObstacle3 = $_POST["autoObstacle3"]; 
$autoObstacle4 = $_POST["autoObstacle4"]; 
$autoObstacle5 = $_POST["autoObstacle5"];
$autoObstacle6 = $_POST["autoObstacle6"];
$autoObstacle7 = $_POST["autoObstacle7"];
$autoObstacle8 = $_POST["autoObstacle8"];
$autoObstacle9 = $_POST["autoObstacle9"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u255789499_me";
$password = "mydongishuge";
$dbname = "u255789499_match";

$connect = mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO scoutData (team, match, highMade, highAttempt, lowMade, lowAttempt, fouls, blocks, picks, hang, comments, obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3, obstacle4, obstacle5, obstacle6, obstacle7, obstacle8, obstacle9, autoHighMade, autoHighAttempt autoLowMade, autoLowAttempt, autoObstacle1, autoObstacle2, autoObstacle3, autoObstacle4, autoObstacle5, autoObstacle6, autoObstacle7, autoObstacle8, autoObstacle9) VALUES('$match','$team','$highMade','$highAttempt','$lowMade','$lowAttempt','$fouls','$blocks','$picks','$hang','$comment','$obstacle1','$obstacle2','$obstacle3','$obstacle4','$obstacle5','$obstacle6','$obstacle7','$obstacle8','$obstacle8','$obstacle9','$autoHighMade','$autoHighAttempt','$autoLowMade','$autoHighAttempt','$autoObstacle1','$autoObstacle2','$autoObstacle3','$autoObstacle4','$autoObstacle5','$autoObstacle6','$autoObstacle7','$autoObstacle8','$autoObstacle9')";

mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with it. But I've been wrong before (constantly actually)

Comment: what does your console said? check "POST"  in console. Also what is the code of  `uploadData.php`?

Comment: You need to debug the request to see what is actually being sent, for which you can use the network tab of the console, and also check your PHP code to see what is received. As an aside, I'm sure you could reduce the code above by using jQuery's `serialize()` method.

Comment: Try changing `"autoObstaclefiveCounter"` to `"autoObstacleFiveCounter"` with capital `F` ? As elements having similar `id` appear to have capital letter for word representation of number

Comment: Just FYI, if you're using JQuery, you can replace all those "document.getElementById('anId')" with "$('#anId')"

Comment: @Sebastianb Yep, the pain of writing that out definitely taught me a good lesson.

Comment: How do you know that your data isn't being sent to PHP?  Are you looking in your console?  Doing a `var_dump`?  Checking the database?  Why are you using `mysql_query` with `mysqli` (shouldn't that be `new mysqli(...)`)?  P.S. ***Please*** don't use this PHP code, it's unsafe.  You should look into using "prepared statements".  What if I did `$('#autoObstacleNineCounter').text("'); DROP TABLE scoutData; -- ")`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know it isn't safe. But I'm not worried about this, as it is for my robotics team only. And I don't need to worry about them doing that.

Comment: @bob: Anyway, how do you know your data isn't being sent?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have used firebug to check and see if it is sending, and it is apparently, but I dont think the php is being ran.

Comment: @bob: The biggest problem I see is that you are using `mysql_query()` along with `mysqli()` (which I assume should actually be `new mysqli()`).  You *cannot* mix those together, you need to use one API.  You need to use `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @bob: Have you tried putting in some `echo`s/`var_dump`s to debug the PHP to see if it's running and/or getting the values?